# How to overcome multiple alert messages

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application, I have one input box and one submit button when user click on submit with empty input box it should show an alert message... but if I submit multiple times with no value in input box it shows multiple alert messages instead of one

```
$('#submit-btn').on('click', function(){
    var input_term = $('#input-box').val();
    if(!input_term.trim()) {
        alertError({
            message: "Missing Token"
        });
     return;
    }
})

function alertError(error) {
    toastr.error(error.message);
}
```

Comment: Please post your code for us to look at

Comment: How are we supposed to help if you don't provide us with any source code? What have you tried to resolve the issue yourself? You may want to look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I think I understand your problem. But, please post your source code for us to help you.

Comment: On click, you can disable button signifying processing is going on and then show alert.  This way multiple click will be blocked and you will get only 1 alert

Answer (score 0):

use preventDefault function..

$('#submit-btn').on('click', function(e){

```
e.preventDefault();
var input_term = $('#input-box').val();
if(!input_term.trim()) {
    alertError({
        message: "Missing Token"
    });
 return;
}
```

});